# Applying default.master to a custom .aspx page in the _layouts folder

Tags: 2007, master-page

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 + C# + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 + ASP.Net. And I am using collaboration portal template.

I am developing a custom aspx page and put it in _layout folder of a site and I want to apply default.master of the SharePoint site to this aspx page. Any samples about how to achieve this goal?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom HttpModule. Check [this](http://www.thelineberrys.com/default-category/using-your-sharepoint-sites-master-page-on-all-application-pages-3.html) sample out.